# Criar coluna no dataframe que contenha a lista com os valores da linha exceto os valores nulos (NaN)

Tags: python, pandas

Código e arquivo utilizados: https://github.com/CaioEuzebio/Python-DataScience-MachineLearning/tree/master/SalesLogistics

Estou trabalhando em uma análise utilizando pandas.
Basicamente preciso classificar as ordens por quantidade de produtos, e que contenha os mesmos produtos.

Exemplo: Eu tenho a ordem 1 e a ordem 2, ambas possuem o produto A e produto B.
Usando como chave a lista de produtos e quantidade de produtos irei criar
uma pivot que vai ter como index essa combinação de produtos e ira me retornar 
as ordem quem possuem os mesmos produtos.

O objetivo gerál da análise é obter um dataframe como o abaixo:

```
dfFinal 

listProds            Ordens  NumProds
[prod1,prod2,prod3]     1       3
                        2
                        3
[prod1,prod3,prod5]     7       3
                        15
                        25
[prod5]                 8       1
                        3
```

Até o momento o código está assim.

Setando como index a coluna 'Ordem' para que a primeira pivot seja feita

```
df1.index=df1['Ordem']
df3 = df1.assign(col=df1.groupby(level=0).Produto.cumcount()).pivot(columns='col', values='Produto')
```

Com essa pivot obtenho o dataframe abaixo.

```
df3 = 

col 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63
Ordem                                                                                   
10911KD YIZ12FF-A   YIZ12FF-A   YIIE2FF-A   YIR72FF-A   YIR72FF-A   YIR72FF-A   NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
124636  HYY32ZY-A   HYY32ZY-A   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1719KD5 YI742FF-A   YI742FF-A   YI742FF-A   YI742FF-A   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
22215KD YI762FF-A   YI762FF-A   YI762FF-A   YI762FF-A   YI762FF-A   YI762FF-A   YI6E2FF-A   YI6E2FF-A   YI6E2FF-A   NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Quando termino de rodar o código, aparece valores NaN, e preciso retirá-los das linhas, para que não influencie na análise que estou fazendo.

Answer (score 0):

Seja o mais simples o possível com o código. Irá lhe ajudar tanto para depuração como para legibilidade do código, no caso, se outra pessoa precisar analisar. Recomendo ler a biblioteca do pandas, que há vários métodos que inibem verbose.

```
import pandas as pd    

# arquivos .csv não especificam a variável
df = pd.read_csv('Sales.csv', dtype={
        "Linha" : int,
        "Quantidade" : int,
        })
# transformar em datetime para facilitar análises de data
df['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df.groupby(['Ordem', 'Produto']).first()
```